# Lubuntu on cubieboard2. alsa-firmware not installing usx2yloader into /usr/bin or /sbin. very stumped!

Tags: sound, lubuntu, alsa

I am combining an usb sound card with a cubieboard2, within a head casing containing two microphones! Binaural microphone! Thats just the basic jist at least ;p

I am currently using Lubuntu 12.10 v1.05 a20 nand image. My goal here is to load alsa-firmware into a Tascam US122 usb audio interface(test unit) While we wait for our own designed sound card to be completed!

I am specifically having an issue with usx2yloader within alsa-firmware. At least I THINK that is the problem! This same process worked perfect on my desktop ubuntu install. I am following this guide [Tascam US122 ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TASCAM_US-122). The guide is slightly old, as far as the old firmware and link go, but I have worked out that problem already.

## Remember this is all using Lubuntu Cubieboard2 a20 image! This is NOT i386     compatible! Armhf please =D

So... After I run this command, with the proper paths, the firmware loads into the Tascam.

```
$ sudo fxload -s /path/to/ld2-ezusb.hex -I /usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122fw.ihx -D /proc/bus/usb/002/003
```

After this I am supposed to run usx2yloader but I get this error.

`$ sudo usx2yloader`

`sudo: usx2yloader: command not found`

I know this looks like a simple fix but it is a lot harder than I could have forseen! As far as I know, you cant just simply install or `sudo apt-get install usx2yloader`. I have tried to just extract alsa-firmare, `cd /usx2yloader` and `make` doesnt work.

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I will install alsa-firmware now and give you the output. Please keep in mind that my alsa install is currently 1.0.25 so i normally would get the alsa-firmware that matches it. Note: I have tried several different alfa-firmware packages such as 1.0.27(current), 1.0.25(same as my Lubuntu installed alsa and alsa-tools) and 1.0.16(the same as my ubuntu desktop install, which was successfull and the Tascam is currently on with a solid green light). For examples sake, I will install 1.0.27(current)

configure

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for as31... no
checking firmware installation directory... /lib/firmware
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating hdsploader/Makefile
config.status: creating mixartloader/Makefile
config.status: creating usx2yloader/Makefile
config.status: creating vxloader/Makefile
config.status: creating pcxhrloader/Makefile
config.status: creating echoaudio/Makefile
config.status: creating emu/Makefile
config.status: creating asihpi/Makefile
config.status: creating korg1212/Makefile
config.status: creating maestro3/Makefile
config.status: creating multisound/Makefile
config.status: creating sb16/Makefile
config.status: creating wavefront/Makefile
config.status: creating ymfpci/Makefile
config.status: creating aica/Makefile
config.status: creating ca0132/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

make

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27$ make
Making all in hdsploader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -                    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-    firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT tobin.o -MD -MP -MF         .deps/tobin.Tpo -c -o tobin.o tobin.c
mv -f .deps/tobin.Tpo .deps/tobin.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o tobin tobin.o  
./tobin
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
Making all in mixartloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/mixartloader'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/mixartloader'
Making all in pcxhrloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
Making all in usx2yloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
Making all in vxloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT toxlx.o -MD -MP -MF         .deps/toxlx.Tpo -c -o toxlx.o toxlx.c
mv -f .deps/toxlx.Tpo .deps/toxlx.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o toxlx toxlx.o  
./toxlx < x1_2_v22.rbt > x1_2_v22.xlx
./toxlx < x1_1_vx2.rbt > x1_1_vx2.xlx
./toxlx < x1_1_vxp.rbt > x1_1_vxp.xlx
./toxlx < x1_1_vp4.rbt > x1_1_vp4.xlx
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
Making all in echoaudio
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-    firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer DSP/LoaderDSP.c loader_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Darla20DSP.c darla20_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Gina20DSP.c gina20_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Layla20DSP.c layla20_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/LaylaASIC.c layla20_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Darla24DSP.c darla24_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Gina24DSP.c gina24_301_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Gina24ASIC.c gina24_301_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Gina24_361DSP.c gina24_361_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Gina24ASIC_361.c gina24_361_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Layla24DSP.c layla24_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Layla24_1ASIC.c layla24_1_asic.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Layla24_2A_ASIC.c layla24_2A_asic.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Layla24_2S_ASIC.c layla24_2S_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/MonaDSP.c mona_301_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Mona1ASIC48.c mona_301_1_asic_48.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Mona1ASIC96.c mona_301_1_asic_96.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Mona361DSP.c mona_361_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Mona1ASIC48_361.c mona_361_1_asic_48.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Mona1ASIC96_361.c mona_361_1_asic_96.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/Mona2ASIC.c mona_2_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/MiaDSP.c mia_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/Echo3gDSP.c echo3g_dsp.fw
./fw_writer ASIC/3G_ASIC.c 3g_asic.fw
./fw_writer DSP/IndigoDSP.c indigo_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/IndigoIODSP.c indigo_io_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/IndigoIOxDSP.c indigo_iox_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/IndigoDJDSP.c indigo_dj_dsp.fw
./fw_writer DSP/IndigoDJxDSP.c indigo_djx_dsp.fw
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
Making all in asihpi
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
Making all in emu
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-    firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
Making all in korg1212
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
Making all in maestro3
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/maestro3'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -        DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-    firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer
writing maestro3_assp_kernel.fw ...
writing maestro3_assp_minisrc.fw ...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/maestro3'
Making all in multisound
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
Making all in sb16
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-    firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer
writing mulaw_main.csp ...
writing alaw_main.csp ...
writing ima_adpcm_init.csp ...
writing ima_adpcm_playback.csp ...
writing ima_adpcm_capture.csp ...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
Making all in wavefront
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/wavefront'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-        firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer
writing yss225_registers.bin ...
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-    1.0.27/wavefront'
Making all in ymfpci
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -    DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"alsa-        firmware\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.27\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT fw_writer.o -MD -MP -    MF .deps/fw_writer.Tpo -c -o fw_writer.o fw_writer.c
mv -f .deps/fw_writer.Tpo .deps/fw_writer.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o fw_writer fw_writer.o  
./fw_writer
writing ds1_dsp.fw ...
writing ds1_ctrl.fw ...
writing ds1e_ctrl.fw ...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
Making all in aica
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
Making all in ca0132
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
```

I noticed this line when doing `make` above. This should be installing right? I think this is where my problem lies...!

```
Making all in usx2yloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

make install

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27$ sudo make install
Making install in hdsploader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/hdsploader'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 digiface_firmware.bin digiface_firmware_rev11.bin     multiface_firmware.bin multiface_firmware_rev11.bin rpm_firmware.bin     '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/hdsploader'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 digiface_firmware.bin digiface_firmware_rev11.bin     multiface_firmware.bin multiface_firmware_rev11.bin rpm_firmware.bin '/lib/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/hdsploader'
Making install in mixartloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-    1.0.27/mixartloader'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-    1.0.27/mixartloader'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/mixartloader'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 miXart.conf miXart8AES.xlx miXart8.elf miXart8.xlx     '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/mixartloader'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/mixart'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 miXart8AES.xlx miXart8.elf miXart8.xlx     '/lib/firmware/mixart'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/mixartloader'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/mixartloader'
Making install in pcxhrloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/pcxhrloader'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pcxhr.conf pcxhr0.conf pcxhr1.conf pcxhr2.conf         pcxhr3.conf pcxhr4.conf pcxhr5.conf xi_1_882.dat xc_1_882.dat e321_512.e56 b321_512.b56         d321_512.d56 xlxint.dat xlxc882hr.dat xlxc882e.dat dspe882.e56 dspb882hr.b56 dspb882e.b56         dspd882.d56 xlxc1222hr.dat xlxc1222e.dat dspb1222hr.b56 dspb1222e.b56 dspd1222.d56         xlxc222.dat xlxc924.dat dspe924.e56 dspb924.b56 dspd222.d56         '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/pcxhrloader'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/pcxhr'
         /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 xi_1_882.dat xc_1_882.dat e321_512.e56     b321_512.b56     d321_512.d56 xlxint.dat xlxc882hr.dat xlxc882e.dat dspe882.e56 dspb882hr.b56 dspb882e.b56     dspd882.d56 xlxc1222hr.dat xlxc1222e.dat dspb1222hr.b56 dspb1222e.b56 dspd1222.d56     xlxc222.dat xlxc924.dat dspe924.e56 dspb924.b56 dspd222.d56 '/lib/firmware/pcxhr'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/pcxhrloader'
Making install in usx2yloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 us122.conf us224.conf us428.conf us122.prepad     us224.prepad us428.prepad us122.rbt us224.rbt us428.rbt tascam_loader.ihx us122fw.ihx     us224fw.ihx us428fw.ihx '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader'
Making install in vxloader
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/vxloader'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 vx222.conf vxboard.conf vxpocket.conf vxp440.conf     bd56002.boot bd563s3.boot bd563v2.boot bx_1_vxp.b56 bx_1_vp4.b56 l_1_v22.d56 l_1_vx2.d56     l_1_vxp.d56 l_1_vp4.d56 x1_2_v22.rbt x1_1_vx2.rbt x1_1_vxp.rbt x1_1_vp4.rbt     '/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/vxloader'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/vx'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bd56002.boot bd563s3.boot bd563v2.boot bx_1_vxp.b56     bx_1_vp4.b56 l_1_v22.d56 l_1_vx2.d56 l_1_vxp.d56 l_1_vp4.d56 x1_2_v22.xlx x1_1_vx2.xlx     x1_1_vxp.xlx x1_1_vp4.xlx '/lib/firmware/vx'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/vxloader'
Making install in echoaudio
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/ea'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 loader_dsp.fw darla20_dsp.fw gina20_dsp.fw layla20_dsp.fw     layla20_asic.fw darla24_dsp.fw gina24_301_dsp.fw gina24_301_asic.fw gina24_361_dsp.fw     gina24_361_asic.fw layla24_dsp.fw layla24_1_asic.fw layla24_2A_asic.fw layla24_2S_asic.fw     mona_301_dsp.fw mona_301_1_asic_48.fw mona_301_1_asic_96.fw mona_361_dsp.fw     mona_361_1_asic_48.fw mona_361_1_asic_96.fw mona_2_asic.fw mia_dsp.fw echo3g_dsp.fw     3g_asic.fw indigo_dsp.fw indigo_io_dsp.fw indigo_iox_dsp.fw indigo_dj_dsp.fw     indigo_djx_dsp.fw '/lib/firmware/ea'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/echoaudio'
    Making install in asihpi
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/asihpi'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 dsp2400.bin dsp5000.bin dsp6200.bin dsp6205.bin     dsp6400.bin dsp6600.bin dsp8700.bin dsp8900.bin '/lib/firmware/asihpi'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/asihpi'
Making install in emu
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/emu'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 hana.fw audio_dock.fw emu0404.fw micro_dock.fw     emu1010_notebook.fw emu1010b.fw '/lib/firmware/emu'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/emu'
Making install in korg1212
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/korg'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 k1212.dsp '/lib/firmware/korg'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/korg1212'
Making install in maestro3
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/maestro3'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-    1.0.27/maestro3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/ess'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 maestro3_assp_kernel.fw maestro3_assp_minisrc.fw     '/lib/firmware/ess'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/maestro3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/maestro3'
Making install in multisound
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-    1.0.27/multisound'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make  install-data-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
/usr/bin/install -c -d /lib/firmware/turtlebeach
cd /lib/firmware/turtlebeach && \
rm -f msndinit.bin && \
ln -s /etc/sound/msndinit.bin msndinit.bin
cd /lib/firmware/turtlebeach && \
      rm -f msndperm.bin && \
      ln -s /etc/sound/msndperm.bin msndperm.bin
cd /lib/firmware/turtlebeach && \
      rm -f pndspini.bin && \
      ln -s /etc/sound/pndspini.bin pndspini.bin
cd /lib/firmware/turtlebeach && \
      rm -f pndsperm.bin && \
      ln -s /etc/sound/pndsperm.bin pndsperm.bin
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/multisound'
Making install in sb16
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/sb16'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mulaw_main.csp alaw_main.csp ima_adpcm_init.csp         ima_adpcm_playback.csp ima_adpcm_capture.csp '/lib/firmware/sb16'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/sb16'
Making install in wavefront
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/wavefront'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/wavefront'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/yamaha'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 yss225_registers.bin '/lib/firmware/yamaha'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/wavefront'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/wavefront'
Making install in ymfpci
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware/yamaha'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ds1_dsp.fw ds1_ctrl.fw ds1e_ctrl.fw     '/lib/firmware/yamaha'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ymfpci'
Making install in aica
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 aica_firmware.bin '/lib/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/aica'
Making install in ca0132
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/firmware'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ctefx.bin ctspeq.bin '/lib/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/ca0132'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27'
```

This is what comes up when I `locate usx2yloader`. I am searching for `/usr/bin/usx2yloader` or `/usr/sbin/usx2yloader`.

```
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/Makefile
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/Makefile.am
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/Makefile.in
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/README
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/an2131.asm
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/tascam_loader.asm
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/tascam_loader.ihx
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us122.conf
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us122.prepad
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us122.rbt
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us122fw.ihx
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us224.conf
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us224.prepad
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us224.rbt
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us224fw.ihx
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us428.conf
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us428.prepad
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us428.rbt
/home/linaro/Downloads/alsa-firmware-1.0.27/usx2yloader/us428fw.ihx
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/tascam_loader.ihx
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.conf
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.prepad
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.rbt
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122fw.ihx
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.conf
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.prepad
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.rbt
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224fw.ihx
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.conf
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.prepad
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.rbt
/usr/local/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428fw.ihx
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/tascam_loader.ihx
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.conf
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.prepad
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122.rbt
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us122fw.ihx
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.conf
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.prepad
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224.rbt
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us224fw.ihx
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.conf
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.prepad
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428.rbt
/usr/share/alsa/firmware/usx2yloader/us428fw.ihx
```

This is all the info I can think of! If you have anything that can help it will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks for your help in advance guys and gals!!

-Halfhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok CL. was correct about `usx2yloader` being a part of `alsa-tools` as far as being installed into `/usr/bin/usx2yloader`. I decided to try and install alsa-tools using [alsa-project downloads](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Download) latest tar file. I removed alsa-tools then downloaded and installed the latest `alsa-tools` tar package from [alsa-tools](ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/tools/).  The folder I extracted alsa-tools into did not have a `configure` file so I searched usx2yloader/ within alsa-tools/ and I found I could configure that separately.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove alsa-tools
$ cd /Downloads/alsa-tools-1.0.27/usx2yloader
$ ./configure;make;makeinstall
```

During `configure` I got this error

```
checking for libasound... no
```

So I downloaded `libasound2 and` libasound2-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

(I also had to run this command to be able to install `libasound2` and `libasound2-dev`. I'm not sure this applies to everyone.)

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

After installing `libasound2` and `libasound2-dev` I was able to `./configure && make && make install` usx2yloader and thus solve this topic!!!

#### Note: I tried installing libasound2 and libasound2-dev BEFORE alsa-tools via apt-get but I still needed to get alsa-tools and install `usx2yloader` separately.

Thank you for your help CL.! You pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The `alsa-firmware` package contains only the firmware itself.

The `usx2yloader` tool can be found in the `alsa-tools` package.

Comment: This was the first page i found. I searched usx2yloader. Are you 100% sure the usx2yloader tool is found in alsa-tools?http://lintian.ubuntuwire.org/quantal/tags/binary-without-manpage.html

Comment: sbin/alsa
alsa-firmware-loaders (binary)
usr/bin/hdsploader
usr/bin/mixartloader
usr/bin/pcxhrloader
usr/bin/sscape_ctl
usr/bin/usx2yloader
usr/bin/vxloader
usr/bin/hdsploader
usr/bin/mixartloader
usr/bin/pcxhrloader
usr/bin/sscape_ctl
usr/bin/usx2yloader
usr/bin/vxloader
alsa-tools (binary)
usr/bin/extract_ac3
usr/bin/sbiload
usr/bin/us428control
usr/bin/extract_ac3
usr/bin/sbiload
usr/bin/us428control

Comment: Apparently, the `alsa-tools` package was split into several Ubuntu packages. But when you download the ALSA package, you need `alsa-tools`.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/armhf/alsa-firmware-loaders Alsa-firmware-loaders is a package that seems to install usx2yloader as well. And that is a part of alsa-tools. This is all very confusing

Comment: I've just gotten home, first thing `sudo apt-get remove alsa-tools alsa-base` then reinstalled. When I done `sudo apt-get install alsa-base` i go this output...(bah...)

        perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale:

Comment: `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` seems to have fixed that :p ok... next...